# Is there any way to validate JSON before decode?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an app that download a file and then decode it expecting a JSON format, when the format is ok everything goes well. If i intentionally mess the json file flash reports a format error and stop the app. Is there a way to handle the error?

Code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;


public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    private var _jsonPath:String = "json_example.txt";

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        request.url = _jsonPath;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
        loader.load(request);
    }


    private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
            var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);
  }
```

You see my problem is right at the end where `var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);` How can I handle in my code if that fails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use try.. catch...

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONParseError;

try
{
var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);
}
catch ( e:JSONParseError )
{
    //do something
    trace(e);
}
finally
{
}
```

This solution uses as3corelib (http://as3corelib.googlecode.com/), if you use JSON.parse() please check the answer from JayC

Comment: that gives me: Scene 1, Layer 'config & data download', Frame 1, Line 37 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: JSONParseError.

Comment: JayC already mentioned it, better use TypeError. I use as3corelib (http://as3corelib.googlecode.com), which defines JSONParseError.

Comment: Hello from the future! This is incredibly taxing when it needs to be attempted multiple times from a URLStream. Is there a better way? Best thing I can think of is to compare brackets and only check then vs every time bytes are available.

Answer (score 3):

Actionscript suppports try/catch.  According to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html, `parse` throws a `TypeError` on failure.  So it looks like something like

```
try
{
    var jsonArray:Array = JSON.parse(loader.data);
}
catch ( e:TypeError )
{
    //do something
}
catch (e: SomethingOtherError)  //not being literal here, just showing 
//you can catch more than one type of exception
{

}
finally
{
    //finally always works, even if the exception is not caught above
}
```

(edited)

The above code shouldn't need your 
`import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;`

The JSONParseError Thorsten mentions seems to be from the <strike>mixpanel library</strike> as3corelib library https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/ which uses the JSONDecoder to deserialize 
https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json/JSONDecoder.as

HOWEVER, if you want to still use the as3corelib library for some reason, to make Thorsten's code work, all you need (IIRC) would be to `import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONParseError;`.

Comment: Doing so, Im still getting an error that blocks the app: JSONParseError: Unexpected s encountered  (where the 's' is an intentionally placed error to mess the json file)

Comment: Also, you are talking about parse but in your example you use decode

Comment: eh, yeah, I got a little lazy, I meant `JSON.parse`.  To use JSON.parse, you'd have to remove the import of the as3corelib JSON class, though.

Comment: That's it, esp. if you get an Error from type JSONParseError :)